# i want to convert all these rows and columns into 2 rows like this from

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, numpy-ndarray

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| Y | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| Z | 11 | 12 | 13 |

I want to convert the above data frame like this

| XA | XB | XC | XD | YA | ..... | ZD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |  | 14 |

please help me with this

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
s = df.stack()
new_df = s.to_frame().T.set_axis([f'{x}{y}' for x, y in s.index], axis=1)

   XA  XB  XC  XD  YA  YB  YC  YD  ZA  ZB  ZC  ZD
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8  11  12  13  14
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible way. First, [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) your data in all its columns but keep the original index:

```
>>> df df = pd.melt(df, value_vars=df.columns, ignore_index=False)
>>> df df
      variable  value
X        A      1
Y        A      5
Z        A     11
X        B      2
Y        B      6
Z        B     12
X        C      3
Y        C      7
Z        C     13
X        D      4
Y        D      8
Z        D     14
```

Now set the new index and transpose the data:

```
>>> df df = df[["value"]].set_index(df.index + df["variable"]).T
>>> df 
       XA  YA  ZA  XB  YB  ZB  XC  YC  ZC  XD  YD  ZD
value   1   5  11   2   6  12   3   7  13   4   8  14
```

Comment: i just want to convert the data data frame as  = X- variable | X-value | Y- Variable | Y-value | Z-var..,    in the first row and the second row should contain respective values. Thank you.